# SQL Case statement applies else clause when condition is true

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rdbms

When I run the following sql query statement it does not format as numeric(10,0)

but numeric(10,3).

If I replace cast(Oct as numeric(10,3)) with null it works.

```
select case when col='Gallons' 
            then cast(Oct as numeric(10,0))
else cast(Oct as numeric(10,3))
end as Oct
from (select 'Gallons' as col, 225.00 as Oct) a
```

Why would it behave in this manner?

Comment: that's because the `CASE` expression must have a unique data type as a result, it can't have 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single type.  It must decide between `numeric(10, 0)` and `numeric(10, 3)`.  The latter is the more general, so it will choose that.

If you want to control what the result set looks like, then convert the value to a string:

```
select (case when col = 'Gallons'
             then cast(cast(Oct as numeric(10, 0)) as varchar(255))
             else cast(cast(Oct as numeric(10, 3)) as varchar(255))
        end) as Oct
from (select 'Gallons' as col, 225.00 as Oct) a
```

You can also do this using the `str()` function.

Comment: I gave up too quickly.  This should work for my purpose.  And yes, it does make since that it would have to output a single type now that it's been pointed out to me.  Just a lack of logical thinking on my part.

Answer (score 0):

To keep both formats you can cast the numeric values to varchar:

```
select case when col='Gallons' then cast(cast(Oct as numeric(10,0)) as varchar(max))
else cast(cast(Oct as numeric(10,3)) as varchar(max)) end as Oct
from (select 'Gallons' as col, 225.00 as Oct union all select 'Other' as col, 123.45 as Oct) a
```

Result:

[image]